# Save away ostringreader.str().c_str()

Tags: c++, ostringstream

Why does the value of text1 change after reading out y in this piece of code?

```
void func()
{
    int value1 = 5;
    double value2 = 1.5;
    std::ostringstream x, y;

    x << value1;
    y << value2;


    const char *text1 = x.str().c_str();
    fprintf(stderr, "text1: v=%s, p=%p\n", text1, &text1);
    const char *text2 = y.str().c_str();
    fprintf(stderr, "text1: v=%s, p=%p\ntext2: v=%s, p=%p\n", text1, &text1, text2, &text2);
}
```

Output:

text1: v = 5, a = 0xbfcfd508

text1: v = 1.5, a = 0xbfcfd508

text2: v = 1.5, a = 0xbfcfd510

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After you have evaluated the `str().c_str()` expression, the temporary `std::string` instance created by the call to `str()` is released and your `char` pointer points into Nirvana. You need to store the return value of `str()`!

Comment: the moral of the story : avoid c_str(), specially of a temporary

Comment: The return value of [c_str](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) is only guaranteed valid until the next non-const operation on the object. The destructor is non-const. So you're storing a result that becomes invalid before you use it.